# DIV position: fixed; Center Horizontally

Tags: css, svg, center, css-position

I am trying to horizontally center a DIV containing SVG files with Fixed position, they all have values for "LEFT" and "TOP" tag in order to position them in order.

Now how to I get the DIV that contains the SVG files (with custom values for TOP and LEFT tag) centred horizontally in the browser, using the FIXED positioning tag so it wont affect the width of the container?

All the CSS code is below. (#gear01-#gear16 are the individual IDs for the SVG files)

```
section.container-gear {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 970px;
    position: fixed;
    top: auto;
    left: 500px;
    z-index: -30;
    border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

```
section.container-gear #gear01 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 192px;
    left: -35px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear02 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 54px;
    left: -34px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear03 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 167px;
    left: 101px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear04 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 29px;
    left: 102px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear05 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 196px;
    left: 236px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear06 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 58px;
    left: 237px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear07 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 171px;
    left: 372px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear08 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 33px;
    left: 373px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear09 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    left: 507px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear10 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 62px;
    left: 508px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear11 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 175px;
    left: 643px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear12 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 37px;
    left: 644px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear13 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 204px;
    left: 778px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear14 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 66px;
    left: 779px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear15 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 179px;
    left: 914px;
    z-index: -25;
}

section.container-gear #gear16 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    fill: rgba(0, 136, 206, 1);
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    top: 41px;
    left: 915px;
    z-index: -25;
}
```

Comment: You set the left position already. You have to use that in order to center it.

Comment: And how do you suggest I retain their position? Percentage will not work as I need them to be spaced exactly to the pixel, since I plan to run an animation with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a first element in position:fixed as a main container, then set inside elements like you would in the flow.
ex : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/bxKuH

```
#fixed {
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:table;
}
#center {
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
p {
  display:inline-block;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```
<div id="fixed">
  <div id="center">
    <p>Center me!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

this should easely include IE8.

vertical-center is an option, it is only to show that you can manage content inside a fixed ccontainer just like in the flow in body tag. :)

Comment: could you tell me wich browser for my own culture ? , do you mean the test page or the use you tried ?

Comment: The script implemented in the project I'm working on. Safari and whatever Coda preview browser is powered by, my guess webkit.

Answer (score 0):

On the div you want to center add: `align="center"`

For example:

```
<div align="center">
     // content
</div>
```

or:

```
margin-left: 50%;
```

or this jquery snippet:

```
$('div').css('margin-left', $(window).width()/2-($('div').width()/2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nvVb7/

if you want to change the object it's aligned in change the window to what you want

make sure you remember an ajax file.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Both align-center and margin-left don't seem to work.

Comment: I've updated the jquery to work better and am just about to add a fiddle